# Ask this finite-dimensional example of RKHS

Tags: functional-analysis

A simple, but fundamentally important, example of an RKHS can be obtained when $E$ is finite-dimensional. Thus, let $E=\{t_1, \ldots, t_p\}$ in which case the kernel $K$ is equivalent to the matrix $\mathscr{K}=\{K\left(t_i, t_j\right)\}_{i, j=1: p}$.

The RKHS is now found to be the set of functions on $E$ of the form
$$
f(\cdot)=\sum_{i=1}^p a_i K\left(\cdot, t_i\right),
$$
where $\left(a_1, \ldots, a_p\right)$ is perpendicular to the null space of $\mathscr{K}:$ i.e., the set of vectors a for which $\mathscr{K} a=0$. Note that $f(\cdot)$ can take on only $p$ values which means that it has a p-vector representation as $\left(f\left(t_1\right), \ldots, f\left(t_p\right)\right)^T=\mathscr{K}$ a for $a=$ $\left(a_1, \ldots, a_p\right)^T$.

For notational clarity in this instance, we will use $f(\cdot)$ to indicate its representation as a function on $E$ and $f$ to denote its vector form. With that convention, the inner product between $f_1(\cdot), f_2(\cdot) \in \mathbb{H}(K)$ is
$$
\left\langle f_1(\cdot), f_2(\cdot)\right\rangle=f_1^T \mathscr{K}^{-} f_2
$$
with $\mathscr{K}^{-}$any generalized inverse of $\mathscr{K}$ : i.e., any matrix that satisfies $\mathscr{K} \mathscr{K}^{-} \mathscr{K}=\mathscr{K}$. The Moore-Penrose generalized inverse of $\mathscr{K}$ is one possible choice for $\mathscr{K}^{-}$and, of course, we use $\mathscr{K}^{-}=\mathscr{K}^{-1}$ when $\mathscr{K}$ is invertible.

**Question 1:** I don't know why we need the constraint that $\left(a_1, \ldots, a_p\right)$ is perpendicular to the null space of $\mathscr{K}$. I know if we choose the vector $\left(a_1, \ldots, a_p\right)$ in the null space of $\mathscr{K}$, then our function $f$ would become a zero function. Thus, we want to avoid any vector from the null space of $\mathscr{K}$. But I don't know why we need the constraint that $\left(a_1, \ldots, a_p\right)$ is perpendicular to the null space of $\mathscr{K}$.

**Question 2:** I try to get $
\left\langle f_1(\cdot), f_2(\cdot)\right\rangle=f_1^T \mathscr{K}^{-} f_2
$. This below is my attempt:

First, recall that for any $f_1(\cdot), f_2(\cdot) \in \mathbb{H}(K)$, we can express them in the form:

$$f_1(\cdot) = \sum_{i=1}^p a_i K(\cdot, t_i)$$
$$f_2(\cdot) = \sum_{j=1}^p b_j K(\cdot, t_j)$$

where $(a_1, \ldots, a_p)$ and $(b_1, \ldots, b_p)$ are perpendicular to the null space of the kernel matrix $\mathscr{K}$.

Now, we can represent $f_1(\cdot)$ and $f_2(\cdot)$ as $p$-dimensional vectors $f_1$ and $f_2$, respectively, by evaluating them at the points $t_1, \ldots, t_p$. That is,

$$f_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
f_1(t_1) \\
\vdots \\
f_1(t_p)
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad f_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
f_2(t_1) \\
\vdots \\
f_2(t_p)
\end{pmatrix}$$

Using the matrix representation of the kernel $\mathscr{K}$, we can write:

$$f_1 = \mathscr{K} \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\
\vdots \\
a_p
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad f_2 = \mathscr{K} \begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\
\vdots \\
b_p
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, the inner product between $f_1(\cdot)$ and $f_2(\cdot)$ in the RKHS $\mathbb{H}(K)$ can be computed using the kernel function $K$ as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
\langle f_1(\cdot), f_2(\cdot)\rangle &= \sum_{i=1}^p \sum_{j=1}^p a_i b_j K(t_i, t_j) \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & \cdots & a_p
\end{pmatrix} \mathscr{K} \begin{pmatrix}
b_1 \\
\vdots \\
b_p
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= f_1^T \mathscr{K} f_2
\end{aligned}$$

I find myself that I didn't get anything about the inverse matrix!